# Why does the shaved head girl (Copperhead?) try to kill Marcus?

Tags: code-8

In the superpowered crime film, *Code 8*, there's a scene where The Trust's enforcer, a woman with a shaved head and a psychotic mindset, suddenly pulls a gun out and apparently tries to shoot Marcus Sutcliffe, only to have his bodyguard (Rhino?) tank the shots with his powers. Shortly thereafter, the woman is zapped by Connor and subsequently killed. Why did she do this? As best I understand, The Trust was planning to get paid from Marcus's upcoming score, so it doesn't profit them to kill him. Right before she does it, she nods to a pair of guys who start hassling the stripper onstage, probably to provide a distraction. Those fellows might be the two who start gunning down officers during the final crime scene, but since they were apparently hired by Marcus, that makes even less sense that they'd try to help kill him, then be working for him.

Is there any indication of why she tried to kill Marcus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**She does try to kill Marcus only after the bank robery goes south.**

It appears evident the fund were aware of the hit and waiting for results on payment. When ultimately that proved to be a failure they simply exercise their justice.

Note she starts the attack the moment they acknowledge the hit was a failure, pointing out to prearranged instructions based on, precisely, that very outcome.